# converting pdf pages to images using js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-conversion

How to export a PDF document into a series of individual images(jpeg, png or bmp format) using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Everything is possible... Though I think you'd have to code quite some to get this done. There is [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) that would help.

By the way, bext time [read the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about what questions are welcome here...

Comment: it is not possible, in order to do it you need addition libraries, So this should be executed on server. JS does not allow this

Comment: JS absolutely allows this; see the aforementioned `pdf.js`.  the more interesting question is, _why_ do you want to do this in JS specifically?

Comment: The more interesting question is *how to do it* rather than *is that possible*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing PDF pages as javascript Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921052/parsing-pdf-pages-as-javascript-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stand corrected, ppeterka is right. 
Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328551/how-to-use-pdf-js) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9328620/588079) where you see a pdf being renderd to canvas, so from there-on you indeed have a image.

Comment: thanks guys..  becuase i have to link this with html page thats why i need it in java script..

Comment: That question seems to have asked for something different, judging by the accepted answer.