# How can I send mail from an Angular web application running in a client's browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, outlook

I'm currently working on an internal project that uses AngularJS on the frontend and queries a C# Web API for data on the backend. Using this setup, I can get most functionality that I'm looking for, but I'd like to add a feature that I believe requires C#, and it isn't really an API call:

When a user clicks a button, I'd like to pop up a new Outlook message with pre-populated recipient and subject fields. I'd also like to be able to pre-include attachments.

I've done this before in C# following steps similar to [these](http://www.developerhandbook.com/c-sharp/how-to-create-a-new-outlook-2013-email-using-c-in-3-simple-steps/), but I'm new to AngularJS and the SPA architecture. Is there a way to implement this feature? Where does the C# code go in the solution, and how do I connect it to the Angular?

Since this is an internal non-customer-facing app, you can assume that all users will have Outlook installed.

Comment: Does a `mailto` link work? I think that's typically how those are implemented.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think that will work for simple emails, but in the future, we may want to have attachments added as well. I'll add that part to the question.

Comment: The real trick is that any C# code will run *on the server* and so cannot just interact with an instance of Outlook (this is true for any web application, not just Angular). What you are asking for may not be possible.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Hmm, now that I think about it, the previous time I did something like this it was in a desktop application, not a web application. We might just have to scrap the feature. I'll leave the question up just in case anyone can suggest an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that native code executes on the server in a web application (not just angular), I don't believe that doing what you are asking is directly possible.

Web applications are heavily sandboxed, directly interacting with a native application is intentionally very difficult. For basic applications I would use `mailto` links as they will open in the users default mail application (presumably Outlook).

If that isn't enough, consider having a form on your page that can be submitted to the server and then send the email on their behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by BradleyDotNET's answer, I've decided to go to with a `mailto` link, which will allow me to fill the subject and recipient fields. 
But to handle attachments, I found the suggestion [here](http://forums.devshed.com/beginner-programming-16/using-mailto-attachment-66699.html) to host the attachments on the site and just put a link to a download in the body of the `mailto`. For PDFs, I can create a view [with the PDF embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html).