# Embed Local docx or pdf file in HTML

Tags: python, html, pdf

I have a quick question that I believe is a simple fix.

I am trying to embed a local PDF into my web application in which I'm using flask to host.

I have tried:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:circle">
  <li><iframe src="/home/name/Desktop/name.pdf"></iframe></li>
```

And it is not working.I have tried removing the path to name.pdf and modifying it as well.

I have also tried a variety of other things.

```
<li><object width="400" height="400" data="name.pdf"></object></li>
```

As well as

```
<li><a href=":/home/name/Desktop/name.pdf">NAME</a></li>
```

I have messed around with the path here, too.

Is this actually possible? I believe it is and my path/to/file is incorrect!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display pdf file in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html)

Comment: this is a different question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a forward slash (`/`). To access a PDF on your local you should use a backslash (`\`). 
Here's an example path to access your PDF on you desktop:

```
<li><iframe src="file:///C:\Users\userName\Desktop\yourPDF.pdf"></iframe></li>
```

To get the correct path, you can drag the PDF into your browser and copy the link from the address bar.

Comment: interesting. I am running on a VM and my path in the browser was:file:///home/name/Desktop/name.pdf

Comment: Must be some other code in your page that breaks it.

Comment: Should use embed not iframe