# PDF/Document preview in django template

Tags: python, django, pdf

I'm really quite new with django and was wondering if there is any way I can show a preview of pdfs/documents inside an html template with django and not another page/tab?

Would like to ask for any insight. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Since Django is just a web server you would need to tackle this through HTML In order to preview a PDF if HTML you would need to use the `embed` tag in the HTML like so.

```
<embed src="path_of_your_pdf/your_pdf_file.pdf" type="application/pdf" height="700px" width="500">
```

If the path to your pdf is stored as a variable in your python code what you can do is

```
<embed src="{{path_to_pdf_file}}" type="application/pdf" height="700px" width="500">
```

You may also want to check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)