# How to preview this pdf in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I was trying to preview this pdf like any other base64 pdf and it was returning blank screen so i checked the content and it left me puzzled. I'm using a **$.ajax response to get its response**. How can I possibly preview the response? Also what kind of encoding are these?

**Preview of response** : JVBERi0xLjUKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9Db250ZW50cyAyIDAgUi9UeXBlL1BhZ2Uv...
**Content-Disposition**: inline; filename="Report.pdf"
**Content-Length**: 5948
**Content-Type**: application/octet-stream
**Actual-Response**: [PDF STRING IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t9Z7.jpg)

Comment: this content will easily downloaded. in form of pdf file but for previewing you need a third party tool.

Comment: a third party tool as ?

Comment: Show the code after the $.ajax call, that's where you are doing something wrong.

Comment: may b this link could be help u...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdf.js` to do so. Its tutorial is available here:
http://usefulangle.com/post/20/pdfjs-tutorial-1-preview-pdf-during-upload-wih-next-prev-buttons

Comment: not working for this case. also it will not work for IE

Comment: yes, pls check the image and provide a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

if pdf.js is not working ,you can try translate response to img, pdf.js i think is the best way to solve pdf preview