# Chrome unable to embeed pdf file in html <object>

Tags: html, object, pdf

im try to embeed pdf file in html object

with mozilla firefox i dont have problem whit this code:

```
<object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
<iframe src="file.pdf" width="300" height="400"></iframe>
</object>
```

and also with this code:

```
<object type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
<embed src="file.pdf" width="300" height="400"/>
</object>
```

firefox doesnt have any problem to open the file , Chrome , IE and other YES
what can i Do to solve this issue ?
thanks a lot
best regards

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: @Charu The embedded tag is for embedded systems, so your advise is plain wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display pdf file in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link

[How to display pdf file in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html)

may help you and give you more description.

Comment: If your answer is nothing but a link to another SO post, the question should be _closed_, not answered. You can flag the question -> should be closed as duplicate, then post the link there.