# How to convert page of node.js web app to a pdf on button click?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am using node, express and ejs to build a web app and I would like to convert a page to a `pdf` on button click.

The route definition for the request created for the button is as follows:

```
const gp = require('./generatePDF');

app.get('/pdf', gp.generatePDF)
```

The function is handled like so:

```
const generatePDF = (request, response) => {
   /* do some stuff to generate content on the ejs page */
   response.render('pages/pagetoconverttoPDF');

}

module.exports = {
  generatePDF,
}
```

What would be the best way to download / view this page as a `pdf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to accomplish this (generating a pdf from html) using `ejs.renderFile` as follows:

```
const generatePDF = (request, response) => {
  var dataToDisplay = request.body;
  ejs.renderFile('./views/pages/admin/employeedatapdf.ejs', {d: dataToDisplay}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          response.send(err);
        } else {
          let options = {
            "height": "11.25in",
            "width": "8.5in",
            "header": {
                "height": "20mm"
            },
            "footer": {
                "height": "20mm",
            },
          };
          let filename = "generatedpdf.pdf";
          pdf.create(data).toFile(filename, function (err, data) {
            let fileloc = 'full path' + filename;
            if (err) {
              response.send(err);
              console.log("error occured")
            } else {
              fs.readFile(fileloc, function (err, data) {
                console.log("generating pdf");
                response.contentType("application/pdf");
                response.send(data);
              });
            }
          })
        }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed a pdf in html, you can either use the `<embed>` tag or `<iframe>` tag. More about that here: [How to display PDF file in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html)

However, if you are looking to serve the pdf standalone, you can static serve the pdf and browsers will render it, along with options to download and print.