# convert base64 pdf src string to url which can be used in img src

Tags: javascript, html

i have a base64 pdf response from api something as:

```
const res = 'JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNCAwIG9iago8PC9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDQ1MD4+c3RyZWFtCnicrVTNctowEL7'
```

I am trying to convert it to image src as follows:

```
<img src={`data:application/pdf;base64,${res}`} alt='not found'/>
```

But getting alt text only and the response is also correct.But when i am using it in

```
<embed src={`data:application/pdf;base64,${res}`} type="application/pdf" />
```

it works fine with embed.
How can i change the base64 string to url which  supports.And how can i print it after preview.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17784037/17635987 Look if there is something useful

Comment: @kirjosieppo using <embed> works.But i need it to be a image.

Comment: Do you mean converting the pdf to a bitmap, like png or jpg?

Comment: @kirjosieppo Yes, to png