# Blazor - Open PDF File in new Tab

Tags: pdf, blazor

I would like to open a pdf document via a button. Is this possible in Blazor?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Blazor runs on the browser. Anything you can do on the browser you can do with Blazor. That includes displaying PDF files using eg the `embed` tag or any of the Javascript viewers. Where is the file stored? On the server? Client? Another web site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display PDF file in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html)

Comment: The file is stored on a server.

Comment: I will try, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use HTML?

Download:

`<a href=@PdfURL download>Download</a>`

or

Open in new tab:

`<a href=@PdfURL target="_blank">Open</a>`

or

Open in current tab (i.e. Navigate to it) :

`<a href=@PdfURL>Open</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution

This is your javascript function

```
function openFile(data) {
    var link = this.document.createElement('a');
    link.download = data.fileName;
    link.href = data.url;
    link.target ="_blank";
    this.document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    this.document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

This is your razor file, replace url with your pdf download url, clicking on button will open pdf in new browser tab

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<button @onclick=@(()=> JS.InvokeVoidAsync("openFile", new {fileName="anyfileName", url="http://anyurl.com"}))>Download PDF</button>
```