# Angular 13 - display base64 in template

Tags: angular

I get following content from my backend (Spring):

```
contentType: application/pdf

content: JVBERi0xLjUKJeLjz9MKNCAwIG9iago8PC9Db2xvclNwYWNlWy9JbmRleGVkL0RldmljZVJHQiAxNii1yoGQsELa5cB0nRP2+O/s8t/H16B+oyPj69CjvmLR3rCHqjKZt1KsxHK+0ZBrlgP///8pXS9NYXNrIFsxNiAxNl0vU3VidHlwZS9JbWFnZS9IZWlnaHQgMjE1L0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9...
```

How can I display that in my template (should be a pdf document). Already tried everything recommended here on SO - but always get a broken image.

tried e.g.:

```
<img [src]="(imageString$ | async) | sanitize" style="width:600px;height:600px">

<img [src] = "'data:image/png;base64,' +imagePath" alt="" style="width:600px;height:600px">
```

but nothing works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide the `component.html` code where you are trying to display this pdf? Right now it is unclear what you are trying to do with this pdf. Open in new window, new tab, iframe, other????

Comment: `imagePath` does not sound like base64 content

Comment: There's some solutions for display of PDFs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html).

Answer (score -1):

You are need 3rd party library or component to display PDF