# Preview PDF file in a HTML modal, then print to a paper size using PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, printing

I need some php or javascript script first to display a PDF file in a HTML modal (client browser) and then to print a PDF file from html modal (client browser) to a standard paper size thermal printer whose dimensions (left, margin, top, bottom margin will be hardcoded)

Output result is to print a receipt for restaurant order on a thermal printer or order receipt (PDF file) could also be sent to email. I already have a script that generates order as a PDF file and save it on a server and attaches to a email then sent. I just need php or javascript script to display PDF file as a preview in a html modal and then to let client print the order receipt to a thermal printer.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Good feedback, I do have order text to print in any format I like including PDF, jpeg, png, html or any other format. Im totally new to this printing thing I would appreciate if you guide me the flow to print a receipt on thermal printer.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question to this one has been asked before on stackoverflow. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html) if you want.

At least you can get detailed information about viewing pdf file in html