# Not able to Render the pdf xml file in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am using firebase for storing the images and files but I am able to render the image in locahost  and i am not able to do for xml ,pdf etc files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Zz9.png)
When i try to render files it is showing some unscripted image.

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avdp2.png)

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  ref,
  uploadBytes,
  getDownloadURL,
  listAll,
  list,
} from "firebase/storage";
import { storage } from "./firebase";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

function App() {
  const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = useState(null);
  const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState([]);

  const imagesListRef = ref(storage, "images/");
  const uploadFile = () => {
    if (imageUpload == null) return;
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `Files/${imageUpload.name + v4()}`);
    uploadBytes(imageRef, imageUpload).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
        setImageUrls((prev) => [...prev, url]);
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    listAll(imagesListRef).then((response) => {
      response.items.forEach((item) => {
        getDownloadURL(item).then((url) => {
          setImageUrls((prev) => [...prev, url]);
        });
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input 
        id="input"
        type="file"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setImageUpload(event.target.files[0]);
        }}
      />


      <button id="button" onClick={uploadFile}> Upload File</button>
      {imageUrls.map((url) => {
        return <img src={url} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `img` tag for displaying pdf and XML?

Comment: @mc-user unfortunately i don't know the tag for pdf and xml could you help me in this

Comment: I think this can help you for pdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784037/how-to-display-pdf-file-in-html