# Convert a Webpage to PDF and Save It In Server - JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, image, pdf

I am working on a project and need two things done

1. Convert a webpage as a PDF file.
2. Save the PDF file in my server.

Basically, the webpage will contain some photos the user will upload and I want to stich all those photos together into a single PDF file and save the PDF file in my web server.

What is the easiest way to do this? JS or PHP anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

You can also take a look at [how-to-use-pdf-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328551/how-to-use-pdf-js)