# Convert html to pdf with pdf.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf.js

I am a complete rookie in js libraries. I want to create an offline application in chrome, which will as a result convert an html file into pdf.

I discovered that it could be done by Mozilla's pdf.js? How can I start it? I am trying to understand the tutorial, but I am missing smth.

I have html page and a javascript file. Where and what shuold I import, and how to export this html file (forms, text and images) into pdf.

Thanx

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328551/how-to-use-pdf-js) might help you.

Comment: Mozilla's pdf.js does the opposite of what you ask. It takes a PDF file and renders it as HTML.

Comment: have a look at [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

Comment: If you are targeting Chrome only, you can focus on your HTML format and look for some extensions https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-or-pdf-with-cleanpr/fklmmmdcofimkjmfjdnobmmgmefbapkf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use pdf.js for this. It can only render (some) files. It does not produce PDF, nor does it handle HTML input.