# Is it possible to read the pdf in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my server i have a pdf. I want to view the pdf in html. But i want only show the first 3 pages only. If user select next it should show next 3 pages. Is it possible in HTML, JavaScript, Jquery?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232916/displaying-pdf-in-jsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
You can go to this link.

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

This library is for reading PDF and and built with HTML5.

There is another Stack Overflow question regarding this issue.

[How to Use pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328551/how-to-use-pdf-js)

Comment: Hi @Reza. THanks for the answer.. But i am getting little confuse. Where i can give the no of pages to display??

Comment: Visit this link :
http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/08/render-pdf-files-with-html5/

Comment: That's what I can see, thanks for pointing it out. Though the documentation said it would support chrome and safari.