# how to save the pdf as image

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save my pdf as image, this is the screen shot of my web page and due to the script, the entire page displays as pdf when i use ctrl+p, now I want this entire pdf as a image how can I do this. I want the image to displayed when i click the "confirm order"  button.

```
<button>Confirm order</button>
```

This is the script i am using for the webpage to be displayed as pdf

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/THREEx.screenshot.js"></script>

<script>
    var dataUrl = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png");
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true   // required to support .toDataURL()
    });

    THREEx.Screenshot.bindKey(renderer);
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF to image using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886042/pdf-to-image-using-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export PDF pages to a series of images in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550129/export-pdf-pages-to-a-series-of-images-in-java)

Comment: All this time I thought that javascript wasn't java

Comment: why are you guys so bothered about javascript is not the same as java. clearly Neeraj Jain was proposing using the backend to prepare the image version of the pdf

Comment: Did you look at libraries such as PDF.js which lets you render image into a canvas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921052/parsing-pdf-pages-as-javascript-images & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328551/how-to-use-pdf-js

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921052/parsing-pdf-pages-as-javascript-images