# How to display a pdf in the browser when uploading the pdf file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project and I want to display a pdf file as well as a text file in my web page

I did manage to display the contents of a text file.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(reader) {
      return function() {
        var contents = reader.result;
        var lines = contents.split('\n');

        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = contents;
      }
    })(reader);

    reader.readAsText(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="backdrop">
    <div class="highlights"></div>
  </div>
  <textarea id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></textarea>
</div>
```

I want to display both text files and PDF files, thanks for your help guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html Has some excellent answers to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) which is community developed and supported by Mozilla Labs.

Looking at their example ["Rendering the Page"](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) is the golden ticket here.

I started off the example by breaking out 2 functions (1 to handle the text files and 1 to handle the PDF files) Take a look at the `handlePDFFile` function and you'll see its somewhat similar, a big difference is we read the file as [reader.readAsDataURL(file);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) instead of reading it as text for the PDF.js library.

for PDF path you will still need to read the file and send the contents of the file to the `pdfjsLib.getDocument` function. After the loading [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is resolved you will be able to handle the `pdf` object.

with the `pdf` object we get the first page and render it onto our canvas. This is only an example so you will need to build on this if you wanted to view multiple pages (only the first page is hard coded).

```js
const PDF_TYPE = "application/pdf";
const TXT_TYPE = "text/plain";

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);


function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    let fileType = files[i].type;
    if (fileType === PDF_TYPE) {
      handlePDFFile(files[i]);
    } else if (fileType === TXT_TYPE) {
      handleTxtFile(files[i])
    } else {
      console.error(`cannot handle file type: ${fileType}`)
    }
  }
}

function handleTxtFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(reader) {
    return function() {
      var contents = reader.result;
      var lines = contents.split('\n');

      document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = contents;
    }
  })(reader);

  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function handlePDFFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (function(reader) {
    return function() {
      var contents = reader.result;
      var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(contents);

      loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
        pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
          var scale = 1.5;
          var viewport = page.getViewport({
            scale: scale,
          });

          var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.height = viewport.height;
          canvas.width = viewport.width;

          var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
          };
          page.render(renderContext);
        });
      });
    }
  })(reader);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```css
#the-canvas {
  outline: black 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.2/pdf.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="backdrop">
    <div class="highlights">

    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea id="container" style="height: 200px; min-width: 200px"></textarea>
  <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: the code works perfectly in run code snippet  but when i actually tried it it doesnt show the html file , i hope u can help me some more

Comment: You should ask another question with more debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR PDF**

Upload your PDF file in Google drive and use its URL in a iframe(like Google Drive) and use its URL in a `iframe`

```
<object data="data/test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="500" height="300">
<a href="data/file.pdf">file.pdf</a>
</object>
```

Also see this link:-[How to Use pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328551/how-to-use-pdf-js)

Comment: thank you for ur help , i want to be able to upload the pdf / text file from my computer and show their content in the same web page